# Contact form that goes to multiple addresses based on drop down selection

Tags: php, beginner, validation, form, email

I followed a tutorial to create a PHP contact form that sends to multiple emails depending on drop down field selection. Is it protected from spam/other dangers? Or is it basically wide open for bots and the like to gain access? I'm a beginner to PHP, and don't really understand what determines the safeness of this code when you have PHP forms going directly to emails. Putting this in the simplest terms possible would be amazing.

```
<?php
require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");
$formproc = new FGContactForm();
$emailAddresses = array(
    'Service Department'=>'fakeemail.com',
    'Sales Department'=>'fakeemail.com',
    'Parts Department'=>'fakeemail.com',
    'Customer Service Department'=>'fakeemail.com',
    'Bids Department'=>'fakeemail.com'
 );
 $emailSubject = 'Submitted from Online Form';
 if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
     if (!isset($emailAddresses[$_POST['destemail']])) {
         exit("Sorry, you have selected an invalid email option.");
     }
     $emailBody = "Dear {$_POST['destemail']}, \n\n {$_POST['message']} \n\n From:          
 {$_POST['name']} \n Company: {$_POST['company']}  \n Phone Number: {$_POST['phone']} \n    
 E-mail: {$_POST['email']}  \n Preferred method of contact: {$_POST['method']} \n\n   
 Submitted from Online 'Contact Us' Form";
     if (mail($emailAddresses[$_POST['destemail']],$emailSubject,$emailBody,"From:    
 {$_POST['company']}")) {
         exit("Email sent successfully");
     } else {
         exit("Email sending failed");
     }
 }
 ?>
```

And some more:

```
<?PHP
/*

*/
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

/*
Interface to Captcha handler
*/
class FG_CaptchaHandler
 {
function Validate() { return false;}
function GetError(){ return '';}
 }
 /*
 FGContactForm is a general purpose contact form class
 It supports Captcha, HTML Emails, sending emails
 conditionally, File atachments and more.
 */
 class FGContactForm
{
var $receipients;
var $errors;
var $error_message;
var $name;
var $email;
var $phone;
var $message;
var $from_address;
var $form_random_key;
var $conditional_field;
var $arr_conditional_receipients;
var $fileupload_fields;
var $captcha_handler;

var $mailer;

function FGContactForm()
{
    $this->receipients = array();
    $this->errors = array();
    $this->form_random_key = 'HTgsjhartag';
    $this->conditional_field='';
    $this->arr_conditional_receipients=array();
    $this->fileupload_fields=array();

    $this->mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
}

function EnableCaptcha($captcha_handler)
{
    $this->captcha_handler = $captcha_handler;
    session_start();
}

function AddRecipient($email,$name="")
{
    $this->mailer->AddAddress($email,$name);
}

function SetFromAddress($from)
{
    $this->from_address = $from;
}
function SetFormRandomKey($key)
{
    $this->form_random_key = $key;
}
function GetSpamTrapInputName()
{
    return 'sp'.md5('KHGdnbvsgst'.$this->GetKey());
}
function SafeDisplay($value_name)
{
    if(empty($_POST[$value_name]))
    {
        return'';
    }
    return htmlentities($_POST[$value_name]);
}
function GetFormIDInputName()
{
    $rand = md5('TygshRt'.$this->GetKey());

    $rand = substr($rand,0,20);
    return 'id'.$rand;
}


function GetFormIDInputValue()
{
    return md5('jhgahTsajhg'.$this->GetKey());
}

function SetConditionalField($field)
{
    $this->conditional_field = $field;
}
function AddConditionalReceipent($value,$email)
{
    $this->arr_conditional_receipients[$value] =  $email;
}

function AddFileUploadField($file_field_name,$accepted_types,$max_size)
{

    $this->fileupload_fields[] =
        array("name"=>$file_field_name,
        "file_types"=>$accepted_types,
        "maxsize"=>$max_size);
}

function ProcessForm()
{
    if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
       return false;
    }
    if(!$this->Validate())
    {
        $this->error_message = implode('<br/>',$this->errors);
        return false;
    }
    $this->CollectData();

    $ret = $this->SendFormSubmission();

    return $ret;
}

function RedirectToURL($url)
{
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}

function GetErrorMessage()
{
    return $this->error_message;
}
function GetSelfScript()
{
    return htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

function GetName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
 function GetPhone()
{
    return $this->phone;
}
function GetEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
function GetMessage()
{
    return htmlentities($this->message,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
}

/*--------  Private (Internal) Functions -------- */


function SendFormSubmission()
{
    $this->CollectConditionalReceipients();

    $this->mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $this->mailer->Subject = "Contact form submission from $this->name";

    $this->mailer->From = $this->GetFromAddress();

    $this->mailer->FromName = $this->name;

    $this->mailer->AddReplyTo($this->email);

    $message = $this->ComposeFormtoEmail();

    $textMsg = trim(strip_tags(preg_replace('/<(head|title|style|script)[^>]*>.*?<\/\\1>/s','',$message)));
    $this->mailer->AltBody = @html_entity_decode($textMsg,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
    $this->mailer->MsgHTML($message);

    $this->AttachFiles();

    if(!$this->mailer->Send())
    {
        $this->add_error("Failed sending email!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function CollectConditionalReceipients()
{
    if(count($this->arr_conditional_receipients)>0 &&
      !empty($this->conditional_field) &&
      !empty($_POST[$this->conditional_field]))
    {
        foreach($this->arr_conditional_receipients as $condn => $rec)
        {
            if(strcasecmp($condn,$_POST[$this->conditional_field])==0 &&
            !empty($rec))
            {
                $this->AddRecipient($rec);
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
Internal variables, that you donot want to appear in the email
Add those variables in this array.
*/
function IsInternalVariable($varname)
{
    $arr_interanl_vars = array('scaptcha',
                        'submitted',
                        $this->GetSpamTrapInputName(),
                        $this->GetFormIDInputName()
                        );
    if(in_array($varname,$arr_interanl_vars))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function FormSubmissionToMail()
{
    $ret_str='';
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(!$this->IsInternalVariable($key))
        {
            $value = htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
            $value = nl2br($value);
            $key = ucfirst($key);
            $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>$key :</div><div class='value'>$value </div>\n";
        }
    }
    foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upload_field)
    {
        $field_name = $upload_field["name"];
        if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
        {
            continue;
        }        

        $filename = basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

        $ret_str .= "<div class='label'>File upload '$field_name' :</div><div class='value'>$filename </div>\n";
    }
    return $ret_str;
}

function ExtraInfoToMail()
{
    $ret_str='';

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $ret_str = "<div class='label'>IP address of the submitter:</div><div class='value'>$ip</div>\n";

    return $ret_str;
}

function GetMailStyle()
{
    $retstr = "\n<style>".
    "body,.label,.value { font-family:Arial,Verdana; } ".
    ".label {font-weight:bold; margin-top:5px; font-size:1em; color:#333;} ".
    ".value {margin-bottom:15px;font-size:0.8em;padding-left:5px;} ".
    "</style>\n";

    return $retstr;
}
function GetHTMLHeaderPart()
{
     $retstr = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">'."\n".
               '<html><head><title></title>'.
               '<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">';
     $retstr .= $this->GetMailStyle();
     $retstr .= '</head><body>';
     return $retstr;
}
function GetHTMLFooterPart()
{
    $retstr ='</body></html>';
    return $retstr ;
}
function ComposeFormtoEmail()
{
    $header = $this->GetHTMLHeaderPart();
    $formsubmission = $this->FormSubmissionToMail();
    $extra_info = $this->ExtraInfoToMail();
    $footer = $this->GetHTMLFooterPart();

    $message = $header."Submission from 'contact us' form:<p>$formsubmission</p><hr/>$extra_info".$footer;

    return $message;
}

function AttachFiles()
{
    foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
    {
        $field_name = $upld_field["name"];
        if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $filename =basename($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);

        $this->mailer->AddAttachment($_FILES[$field_name]["tmp_name"],$filename);
    }
}

function GetFromAddress()
{
    if(!empty($this->from_address))
    {
        return $this->from_address;
    }

    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    $from ="nobody@$host";
    return $from;
}

function Validate()
{
    $ret = true;
    //security validations
    if(empty($_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()]) ||
      $_POST[$this->GetFormIDInputName()] != $this->GetFormIDInputValue() )
    {
        //The proper error is not given intentionally
        $this->add_error("Automated submission prevention: case 1 failed");
        $ret = false;
    }

    //This is a hidden input field. Humans won't fill this field.
    if(!empty($_POST[$this->GetSpamTrapInputName()]) )
    {
        //The proper error is not given intentionally
        $this->add_error("Automated submission prevention: case 2 failed");
        $ret = false;
    }

    //name validations
    if(empty($_POST['name']))
    {
        $this->add_error("Please provide your name");
        $ret = false;
    }
    else
    if(strlen($_POST['name'])>50)
    {
        $this->add_error("Name is too big!");
        $ret = false;
    }

    //phone validations
    if(empty($_POST['phone']))
    {
        $this->add_error("Please provide your phone number");
        $ret = false;
    }
    else
    if(strlen($_POST['phone'])>50)
    {
        $this->add_error("Phone number is too big!");
        $ret = false;
    }

    //company validations
    if(empty($_POST['company']))
    {
        $this->add_error("Please provide your company's name");
        $ret = false;
    }
    else
    if(strlen($_POST['company'])>50)
    {
        $this->add_error("Company name is too big!");
        $ret = false;
    }


    //email validations
    if(empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $this->add_error("Please provide your email address");
        $ret = false;
    }
    else
    if(strlen($_POST['email'])>50)
    {
        $this->add_error("Email address is too big!");
        $ret = false;
    }
    else
    if(!$this->validate_email($_POST['email']))
    {
        $this->add_error("Please provide a valid email address");
        $ret = false;
    }

    //message validaions
     if(empty($_POST['message']))
    {
        $this->add_error("Please provide your message");
        $ret = false;
    }
    else
    if(strlen($_POST['message'])>2048)
    {
        $this->add_error("Message is too big!");
        $ret = false;
    }

    //method validaions
     if(empty($_POST['method']))
    {
        $this->add_error("Please choose method");
        $ret = false;
    }


      //destemail validaions
     if(empty($_POST['destemail']))
    {
        $this->add_error("Please select a department");
        $ret = false;
    }

    //captcha validaions
    if(isset($this->captcha_handler))
    {
        if(!$this->captcha_handler->Validate())
        {
            $this->add_error($this->captcha_handler->GetError());
            $ret = false;
        }
    }
    //file upload validations
    if(!empty($this->fileupload_fields))
    {
     if(!$this->ValidateFileUploads())
     {
        $ret = false;
     }
    }
    return $ret;
}

function ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes)
{
    $ret=true;
    $info = pathinfo($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);
    $extn = $info['extension'];
    $extn = strtolower($extn);

    $arr_valid_filetypes= explode(',',$valid_filetypes);
    if(!in_array($extn,$arr_valid_filetypes))
    {
        $this->add_error("Valid file types are: $valid_filetypes");
        $ret=false;
    }
    return $ret;
}

function ValidateFileSize($field_name,$max_size)
{
    $size_of_uploaded_file =
            $_FILES[$field_name]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs
    if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_size)
    {
        $this->add_error("The file is too big. File size should be less than $max_size KB");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function IsFileUploaded($field_name)
{
    if(empty($_FILES[$field_name]['name']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$field_name]['tmp_name']))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function ValidateFileUploads()
{
    $ret=true;
    foreach($this->fileupload_fields as $upld_field)
    {
        $field_name = $upld_field["name"];

        $valid_filetypes = $upld_field["file_types"];

        if(!$this->IsFileUploaded($field_name))
        {
            continue;
        }

        if($_FILES[$field_name]["error"] != 0)
        {
            $this->add_error("Error in file upload; Error code:".$_FILES[$field_name]["error"]);
            $ret=false;
        }

        if(!empty($valid_filetypes) &&
         !$this->ValidateFileType($field_name,$valid_filetypes))
        {
            $ret=false;
        }

        if(!empty($upld_field["maxsize"]) &&
        $upld_field["maxsize"]>0)
        {
            if(!$this->ValidateFileSize($field_name,$upld_field["maxsize"]))
            {
                $ret=false;
            }
        }

    }
    return $ret;
}

function StripSlashes($str)
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return $str;
}
/*
Sanitize() function removes any potential threat from the
data submitted. Prevents email injections or any other hacker attempts.
if $remove_nl is true, newline chracters are removed from the input.
*/
function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
{
    $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

    if($remove_nl)
    {
        $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
            '/(\r+)/i',
            '/(\t+)/i',
            '/(%0A+)/i',
            '/(%0D+)/i',
            '/(%08+)/i',
            '/(%09+)/i'
            );
        $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
    }

    return $str;
}

/*Collects clean data from the $_POST array and keeps in internal variables.*/
function CollectData()
{
    $this->name = $this->Sanitize($_POST['name']);
    $this->email = $this->Sanitize($_POST['email']);

    /*newline is OK in the message.*/
    $this->message = $this->StripSlashes($_POST['message']);
}

function add_error($error)
{
    array_push($this->errors,$error);
}
function validate_email($email)
{
    return eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", $email);
}

function GetKey()
{
    return $this->form_random_key.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since only addresses from `$emailAddresses` are allowed, it is not possible to inject other addresses. So the form is protected against being used as a spam relay.

On the other hand, you're instantiating a mailer and captcha class, but not using it. So you don't benefit from its protection features. Maybe you use it to create and display the form itself, but you should use to sanitize and send the mail, too. The documentation of `FGContactForm` should help you with that.